# Apple search ads popularity index: how to get one programmatically?

Tags: apple-search-ads

The question is very simple how to get Apple search ads popularity index for any given keyword?

It's possible since i see a lot of ASO tools provide such metric. But there are not any open API documentation how to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way is to parse searchads.apple.com to get one. Or to use Jailbroken iPhone to create requests and get responses directly from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

For getting search popularity index you can also google for chrome extension like „ Apple Search Ads Search Popularity for ASO“

If you want to check your app ranking or get keyword suggestions for different appstore countries you can use this app https://applab.cloud ( I am from Germany and getting insights from US AppStore with this app )